# Firebase Unlink ProviderId issue(email in Identifier still remain)

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

In my Flutter project, I additionally connected a Google Account using `Firebase.instance.currentUser.link`
and then disconnected it by using `Firebase.instance.currentUser.unlink(providerID)`.

After Unlink, in the Firebase Console Google Login is properly deleted from the Authentication provider, but the email address remains in the Identifier.

I want to unlink both Email in Identifier and Provider

[My pubspect.yaml]_ Flutter Project

```
firebase_core :^2.15.0
firebase_auth :^4.7.2
```

Comment: Can you show the code or a screenshot of what you mean with "the email address remains in the Identifier"?